# django channels WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/' failed:

Tags: javascript, python, django, chat, asgi

I'm making a streaming website. I use django channels for this. The first part of the application is a chat in which the name is entered and a room is entered. But when I run the javascript I get an error that the connection failed and the connection is closed according to my reference console.log() . I don't find any problems in my code and chatGPT doesn't find them either. According to chatGPT it may be because my browser does not accept the type of connection through the firewall. I leave my code in case you can help me. Thanks

Error in the browser console:

WebbSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/' failed:

Line marked as error in the console:

webSocket = new WebSocket(endPoint);

Javascript:

```
var inputUsername = document.querySelector('#username');
var btnJoin = document.querySelector('#btn-join');

var username;
var webSocket;
function webSockedOnMessage(event){
    var parseData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var message = parseData['message'];
    console.log('message: ', message);
}

btnJoin.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    username = inputUsername.value;
    if (username == ''){
        return;
    }
    else{
       inputUsername.value ='';
       inputUsername.disabled = true;
       inputUsername.style.visibility = 'hidden';

       btnJoin.disabled= true;
       btnJoin.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       var labelUsername = document.querySelector('#label-username');
       labelUsername.innerHTML = username; 

    }

    var loc = window.location;
    //ws Start specify we are using websockets
    var wsStart = 'ws://';

    if (loc.protocol == 'https:'){
        wsStart = 'wss://'

    }
    //The url in our websocket to connect the consumer
    var endPoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname;
    console.log(endPoint);
    webSocket = new WebSocket(endPoint);

    webSocket.addEventListener('open', (e)=>{console.log('Connection Opened');});
    webSocket.addEventListener('message', webSockedOnMessage);
    webSocket.addEventListener('close', (e)=>{console.log('Connection Closed', e);});
    webSocket.addEventListener('error', (e)=>{console.log('Error Ocurred!', e)});
})
```

consummers.py:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'My_Room'
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
    
    
    
    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        print('Disconected')
    
   
   
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        receive_dict = json.loads(text_data)
        message = receive_dict['message']
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.room_group_name, { 'type':'send.message','message': message})


        async def send_message(self, event):
            message = event['message']

            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message':message}))
```

Routing.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers


websocket_urlpatterns =[

    re_path(r'', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi(),)

]
```

asgi.py:

```
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
# Initialize Django ASGI application early to ensure the AppRegistry
# is populated before importing code that may import ORM models.
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(
     chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
    ))
})
```